# Need a Javascript 'play/pause/stop' control

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a control I can dump on a page. Something like this:

[image]

The key requirement here is the ability to tell the control to fire an event every x seconds. Does something like this exist? I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: What do you want to play? Video? Audio? _____?

Comment: Not much reinventing to do. 2 divs, some CSS and a timer is all you need.

Comment: One div if it's fixed width..

Comment: No video/audio - every x seconds I need to redraw my SVG graph with new params.